# SQLite Exception in .NET MAUI

Tags: sqlite, maui

When running a .NET MAUI application, I get an error

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an    exception.'

which is related to SQLite. I don't know how to solve it, I looked at some suggestions to clean and rebuild the application, but I tried that and it was unsuccessful.

Do you have any effective solution? I followed the tutorial on YT through which I did this, on the video everything works but I get an error... I'm in the process of learning .NET MAUI and this is my first time working with a database so I don't know what to do..

Thank you in advance!

I added these NuGet packages to the project:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm" Version="7.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.6.292" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRawEx.bundle_green" Version="2.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRawEx.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.0" />
```

Comment: what is the InnerException?

Comment: @Jason - System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.' It just shows this error in the window frame, nothing else. ('The application is in break mode - Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)'.

Comment: you need to examine the exception object and look for more info - the InnerException and StackTrace are usually the most relevant

Comment: As Jason said, you need to provide the detailed cause of the error, you can use [InnerException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=net-7.0#code-try-2) to get the exception instance that caused the current exception. You can also step through the code by adding breakpoints to determine the scope of the error. You can refer to the official document to try:[.NET MAUI local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-7.0).